# Can i use regex to find the index of X?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a big string, and want to find the first occurrence of X, X is "numberXnumber"... 3X3, or 4X9...

How could i do this in C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, regex could do that for you

you could do `([0-9]+)X([0-9]+)` If you know that the numbers are only single digit you could take `[0-9]X[0-9]`

Answer (score 56):

```
var s = "long string.....24X10     .....1X3";
var match = Regex.Match(s, @"\d+X\d+");
if (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Index); // 16
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value); // 24X10;
}
```

Also take a look at `NextMatch` which is a handy function

```
match = match.NextMatch();
match.Value; // 1X3;
```

Answer (score 10):

For those who love extension methods:

```
public static int RegexIndexOf(this string str, string pattern)
{
    var m = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
    return m.Success ? m.Index : -1;
}
```

Comment: Using m.Success is the way. Otherwise `Regex.Match("foo", "f").Index == Regex.Match("bar", "f").Index`

Answer (score 3):

this may help you

```
   string myText = "33x99 lorem ipsum  004x44";

    //the first matched group index
    int firstIndex =  Regex.Match(myText,"([0-9]+)(x)([0-9]+)").Index;

    //first matched "x" (group = 2) index 
    int firstXIndex =  Regex.Match(myText,"([0-9]+)(x)([0-9]+)").Groups[2].Index;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var index = new Regex("yourPattern").Match("X").Index;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the number, or the index of the number? You can get both of these, but you're probably going to want to take a look at [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html)

The actual pattern is going to be `[0-9]x[0-9]` if you want only single numbers (89x72 will only match 9x7), or `[0-9]+x[0-9]+` to match the longest consecutive string of numbers in both directions.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/download/csharpregexdemo.zip

You can use this pattern:

> \d([xX])\d

If I test

> blaat3X3test

I get:

> Match offset: 5 Match length: 3
>   Matched text: 3X3 Group 1 offset: 6
>   Group 1 length: 1 Group 1 text: X