# How to implement "Find, Replace, Next" in a String on C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I'm searching for a solution to this case:

I have a Method inside a DLL that receive a string that contains some words as "placeholders/parameters" that will be replaced by a result of another specific method (inside dll too)

Too simplificate: It's a query string received as an argument to be on a method inside a DLL, where X word that matchs a specifc case, will be replaced.

My method receive a string that could be like this:

*(on .exe app)*

```
string str = "INSERT INTO mydb.mytable (id_field, description, complex_number) VALUES ('#GEN_COMPLEX_ID#','A complex solution', '#GEN_COMPLEX_ID#');"

MyDLLClass.MyMethod(str);
```

So, the problem is: if i replace the #GEN_COMPLEX_ID# on this string, wanting that a different should be on each match, it not will happen because the replaced executes the function in a single shot (not step by step). So, i wanna help to implement this: a step by step replace of any text (like Find some word, replace, than next ... replace ... next... etc.

Could you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you need regexes, or is it going to be simply replacing a simple placeholder? How "big" is this string? Is it in a file? Does it need to be loaded in memory in that case? Why don't you replace placeholders before concatenating? What does "Next" mean for you? Do you have some sort of a GUI which should allow user to step through the string?

Comment: Thanks for rapid response.

Comment: Why don't you replace placeholders one by one, inside the `for` loop?

Comment: The Regex implemented is just to "extract" everything #inside#, and I already implemented it. This string is an query string for database selects, inserts, etc, and it's not a file (yes, loaded in memory). I did try to replace before concatenating, but, imagine that this string will  be received as an parameter, an already concatened. The solution  would be string.split(char.Parse(";"), because ";" it's char that determines the end of query (instruction), but could be anothers ";" in the middle of the whole string, so, not good too. Next is like: find placeholder, replace it, next.. means loop

Comment: look at the answer of @James Kyburz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591747/can-i-use-regex-to-find-the-index-of-x You are able to loop trough all matches with `.NextMatch`, also I would recommend you to use StringBuilder when concatenating strings and only when you've done with the concatenation transform it to string, because concatenation the way you are doing it creates a new object each time, and it is a waste of resources

Comment: From what I see your placeholders are parameters of SQL commands so why you didn't use SQL parameters?(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements).

Comment: @NValchev, the string (short o big) is an argument sent by another app to this method inside a dll (so, i'm working on dll side).

Comment: @MichałKomorowski, it's not SQL parameter, this place holders are  a way to call a method to generate, for an example, a complex id without intervention of client app. All work must be done through the DLL.

Comment: @AlissonSantos: have you tried anything yourself? It's pretty straighforward to do it by searching for placeholders using `string.IndexOf` and appending data into a new `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works pretty well for me:

```
        string yourOriginalString = "ab cd ab cd ab cd";
        string pattern = "ab";
        string yourNewDescription = "123";
        int startingPositionOffset = 0;
        int yourOriginalStringLength = yourOriginalString.Length;

        MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(yourOriginalString, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

        foreach (Match m in match)
        {
            yourOriginalString = yourOriginalString.Substring(0, m.Index+startingPositionOffset) + yourNewDescription + yourOriginalString.Substring(m.Index + startingPositionOffset+ m.Length);
            startingPositionOffset = yourOriginalString.Length - yourOriginalStringLength;
        }
```

Comment: that's the solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: While this will provide correct results, it is recommended to compose the output string using a `StringBuilder`, instead of concatenating, since the latter creates new string instances in each operation. This means that this algorithm is esaentially `O(n*m)`, if *n* is length and *m* is the placeholder count, while also creating unneessary GC burden (*m* allocations of length *n*, followed by *m* collections). `Regex.Replace` also uses a `StringBuilder` internally.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the split method like this

```
        string [] placeholder = {"#Placeholder#"} ;
        string[] request = cd.Split(placeholder, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        StringBuilder requetBuilding = new StringBuilder();
        requetBuilding.Append(request[0]); 
        int index = 1; 
        requetBuilding.Append("Your place holder replacement");
        requetBuilding.Append(request[index]); 
        index++;  //next replacement 
                  // requetBuilding.Append("Your next place holder replacement");
                  // requetBuilding.Append(request[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're asking is how to replace each placeholder with a different value, you can do it using the [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx) overload which accepts a `MatchEvaluator` delegate, and executes it for each match:

```
// conceptually, something like this (note that it's not checking if there are
// enough values in the replacementValues array)

static string ReplaceMultiple(
      string input, string placeholder, IEnumerable<string> replacementValues)
{
    var enumerator = replacementValues.GetEnumerator();
    return Regex.Replace(input, placeholder, 
        m => { enumerator.MoveNext(); return enumerator.Current; });
}
```

This is, of course, presuming that all placeholders look the same.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code

```
var split = source.Split(placeholder); // create array of items without placeholders
var result = split[0]; // copy first item
for(int i = 1; i < result.Length; i++)
{
    bool replace = ... // ask user
    result += replace ? replacement : placeholder; // to put replacement or not to put
    result += split[i]; // copy next item
}
```