# Regex - Match emoticon :P but ignore when inside <code></code> tags

Tags: regex

I'm developing a Smarty modifier that allows me to use emoticons in addition to several other things. Everything is fine but I've never been so good with regex so I need help. This is my string:

```
:P <code>:P : P hello : P</code> :P [sub]ssss[/sub]<b>:P</b> : P
```

I'm replacing **:P** with the "smile" emoticon that we all know but the problem is that I do not want to replace **:P** with my "smile" inside code tags:

```
<code></code>
```

In other words everything inside the above tag should be ignored. The replacement should work only for all the **:P** outside. Until now this is what I managed to achieve:

```
\<code\>(^(.*?))\<\/code\>|:P
```

But it only matches the first **:P** then stops when code tag starts. Let me make it even more clear.

```
:P <code>:P : P hello : P</code> :P [sub]ssss[/sub]<b>:P</b> : P
```

I have to match the first **:P**, not the second inside code, the third between the code closing tag and [sub] is valid and the one inside b tags too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are not allowing functional characters (like e.g. ">") in the text or replacing them with e.g. html entities. if so, check if this works for you:

```
(?<disregard>\<code\>[^>]*\</code\>)|(?<capture>:P)
```

The "disregard" group will eliminate all your code and leave the outside for the "captures" to be found.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I think that your idea is brilliant but I can't get it to work as I want. It's 3 days that I'm playing with your regex. Take a look at this fork (https://regex101.com/r/eC1jT8/2). As you can see I can successfully match all occurrences but I don't know how to exclude the disregard caputuring group. I need to match everything with the exception of "disregard". I tryed with !, : etc with no success.

Comment: I am not clear what you want to do. You said you would like to replace all the emoticons. You can replace all the occurrences of the "capture" group and rebuild the string, you don't need to do anything with the "disregard" group. You might want to check my answer in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933069/how-to-implement-find-replace-next-in-a-string-on-c/26934430#26934430) to see if it`s relevant.