# is there such a thing as IndexOf(any white character, startIndex)?

Tags: c#, regex, indexof

A white space character is a single space, a tab, return, and new line. To detect these, use this regular expression: \s

My question is: Is there a way for me to use a single IndexOf statement that will return the index of any white space character?

```
//works
int index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(' ', 0);
int index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf('\n', 0);

//doesn't work
int index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf('\\s', 0);
int index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("\\s", 0);
```

'\S' causes an error that there are too many characters while "\s" ends up looking for \s in a string just looking for a in "heaven". I don't mind checking each type but if there is a better way, please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591747/can-i-use-regex-to-find-the-index-of-x

Comment: _regular expression: \s_ If you know that, why don't you use a RegEx???

Comment: You can use [`string.IndexOfAny(char[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexofany?view=netframework-4.8) with a char array of possible whitespace characters.

Comment: I was in the process of posting an answer when it closed, but [here, you can try it out](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mcE8gD) on DotNetFiddle.

Comment: Sorry TaW and Camilo but i'm interested in IndexOf specifically so I'm not sure why I lost a point. I was looking for IndexOf answers/topics. So thank you @RonBeyer for the answer. I will check it our right away

Comment: With `char[] whites = { ' ', '\t', '\v' };` you can use this instead of IndexOf: `var index = hay.Split(whites )[0].Length;` or Ron's suggestion `IndexOfAny`.

Comment: @TaW if you can, edit the title. should have been IndexOf(any white character, index) because that's what i was really looking for. As such, this is not a duplicate question but -1 for not writing it properly. anyways your answer along with Ron's helped thank you again

Comment: You can use StartIndex directly with IndexOfAny. For the split solution you need to use ` hay.Substring(StartIndex ).Split(...`.

Comment: @Ron, I think you should add the comment as an answer.

Comment: @TaW Thanks, since the question was re-opened I could finish the answer I started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`string.IndexOfAny(char[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexofany?view=netframework-4.8) will get you the index of the string where the first character of any of the characters in the array appears.

The trick is defining what "whitespace" is. The example below has 25 characters defined as whitespace, the more common ones being `' ', '\n', '\t', '\v', '\r'`. The following will use the unicode definitions and `char.IsWhitespace` to determine what whitespace characters there are.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var wsChars = Enumerable.Range(0, ushort.MaxValue)
                            .Where(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(Convert.ToChar(c)))
                            .Select(c => Convert.ToChar(c)).ToArray();

    Console.WriteLine(wsChars.Length);

    var someText = "This_is_a\tstring with \nsome whitespace characters.";

    Console.WriteLine(someText.IndexOfAny(wsChars));
}
```

[Try it out on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mcE8gD)

If you want to start at a specific index, just use the [`string.IndexOfAny(char[], int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexofany?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_IndexOfAny_System_Char___System_Int32_) to provide a starting index.